# Java ee NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, java-ee-8

I'm learning jee. I use intellij idea with apache tomcat (I have the same problem with glassfish). I'm working on the default template, so I didn't change any file and I have a problem when my servlet is called.
Tomcat prints the error :

```
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I see that the base class HttpServlet is not found. I have already added the dependency to my pom.xml file :

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My question is : how can I resolve this problem ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it Tomcat 10?

Comment: Yes it is tomcat 10.0.4

Comment: You need to use [`jakarta.servlet-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/5.0.0), version 5.0.0.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I was using the wrong import 
After adding the new dependency with maven and replacing the import, it worked
Thanks